# UIAlertView and Core Data

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Hi to all of stackoverflow,
i'm Italian so, i'm sorry for my bad English... :D

i tried to create a simple tableView for listing a few names and a number... all with core data.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  Track *track = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  if(YES == self.editing) {
      UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Modifica nome" message:@"Prego, inserire di seguito il nuovo nome:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Annulla" otherButtonTitles:@"Salva", nil];
      newname = [[alert addTextFieldWithValue:track.name label:@"Nome"] text];
      [alert textField].autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
      [alert show];
      [alert release];
      [selectedTrack release];
  } else {
      UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Aggiungi minchiate" message:@"Sei sicuro di voler aggiungere una michiata a" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Annulla" otherButtonTitles:@"Salva", nil];
      newname = [[alert addTextFieldWithValue:track.trackAbstract label:@"Minchiate"] text];
      [alert textField].autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
      [alert show];
      [alert release];
      [selectedTrack release];
  }
}
```

I want to send the value of the textfield to my attributes that i've created first...
Need I put the code in this method?!

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView willDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
    {
        //HERE?!
    }
}
```

And how i can set a new value on a core data attribute? 
ANY help is appreciated... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you would put the code to grab the value from the text field in the `alertView:willDismissWithButtonIndex:`
 method. Assuming you've created a model class for that entity (which I assume you have, as I see a class called `Track` in your code), you can set the value of an attribute by using dot syntax:

`Track.someAttribute = newValue`

Or without dot syntax, it would be `[Track setSomeAttribute:newValue]`.

Also, note that `UIAlertView`'s `addTextFieldWithValue:label:` is an undocumented method, which isn't a problem if this is an app you're planning to create just for yourself, but using it in an app submitted to the App Store will likely get it rejected.

Comment: yeah, the app isn't for app store... :)
mmm, i've got another problem: Track.track.name = newname;
error: request for member 'name' in something not a structure or union... warn: local declaration of 'newname' hides istance variable

ah, i've added this too [[alert textField] becomeFirstResponder];
any ideas?